# Java Comparator.NullLast throwing NPE

Tags: java, sorting, comparator

Sorting a map <String, Object>

String value can be a Integer, Double or a normal (have to parse String into Integer)

[at a time, all keys will be one data type only]

keys cans be null

```
nullsLast(comparing(o -> Double.valueOf(o.getKey())));
```

is throwing NPE.

What to do to make it work?

Comment: `Double.valueOf ` will throw an NPE

Comment: how to handle this

Answer (score 2):

It's not `nullsLast` which is throwing the NullPointerException, but the `Double.valueOf(String)` method.

You can handle this by checking for nulls explicitly.

The second problem is that `comparing` doesn't support null values. What you want to do is compare the object by their key (parsed as Double), using the `nullsLast` comparator to compare the keys:

```
comparing(o -> o.getKey() == null ? null : Double.valueOf(o.getKey()), nullsLast(Comparator.naturalOrder()));
```

Comment: ```
   public static <T, U extends Comparable<? super U>> Comparator<T> comparing(
            Function<? super T, ? extends U> keyExtractor)
    {
        Objects.requireNonNull(keyExtractor);
        return (Comparator<T> & Serializable)
            (c1, c2) -> keyExtractor.apply(c1).compareTo(keyExtractor.apply(c2));
    }
```

it's failing with NPE inside the comparing function

Comment: @moovon Yes, I shouldn't post code without trying it out myself...